# Making a watched folder wait for a file to finish rendering

Tags: macos, shell, ffmpeg

I'm trying to setup a watched folder (using fswatch)that starts to convert a received file into another format using ffmpeg(got that part sorted out).
So far so good, what I'm having problems with is getting the script to wait until the original input (or master file) has finished rendering or has been copied completely into my watched folder.

Here's the script for the folder

```
fswatch -o ~/Desktop/autom_shell| xargs -n1 ~/Desktop/scripts_autom_shell/move_QT.sh
```

move_QT.sh filters and moves quicktime movies from my receiving folder to the folder where I encode.

I've searched for a solution and found [kqwait](http://clojurehackers.com/p/Calvin-L/kqwait) but I have absolutely no idea how to apply it in my case.

MacOS 10.10

Answer (score 0):

I've looked at the source for kqwait, and read the doc on fswatch, and despite the name of kqwait, most of these utilities have the same basic design.

They wait for notifications that operations are occurring in a filesystem, meaning deletes, renames and writes. What they can't really do is notify you when an operation from an application has completed. There is a notification relative to "write" notices indicating the file has been closed, but the intent of most of these utilities is not to wait for that to happen (despite the name of kqwait).

Most of these utilities are meant to wait until just about anything on the filesystem happens, filtered to react on specific files or directories in that filesystem. Only if you can wait for a close notification for a series of write notices would you have a chance of doing what you intend. Even then, it's not clear that a close notification actually and reliably indicates the reception of the file is complete. It merely means writing stopped. Without knowing the application's behavior, that may mean the connection was dropped and the file is incomplete, and might be resumed in a subsequent attempt.

What you really need is the ability to receive a notice on a much higher level event than what's going on in the filesystem.

Barring that, however, the best you can manage is to respond to the fswatch (or similar command), which indicates writing has started, then monitor any new file(s) you determine are incoming files of interest, over time to see if they continue to grow (or you continue to receive notices from fswatch that writing has continued). Then, after sufficient time has passed where the script observes the file size is no longer growing, or that a sufficient time has passed where fswatch is no longer notifying writes are occurring, you could make the assumption that the file is complete and attempt to launch conversion.

That is more than a correction to a sample post - it's writing a script of some limited complexity choosing any one of multiple avenues of design, all of which are based on unclear assumptions (how much time should pass before one assumes reception is finished, for example).

Comment: "Without knowing the application's behavior, that may mean the connection was dropped and the file is incomplete, and might be resumed in a subsequent attempt."

Basically the CPU usage goes through the roof. If the application is idling or busy with editing tasks(Avid Media Composer or Final Cut) the CPU load is between 1.5 and 15 on whatever scale, while it might go up to 1.500 when rendering. I got this numbers from using 

ps -xco %cpu,command | grep AvidMediaComposer

which is a sample of code I found in an Applescript

Comment: Sorry, new here, having problems with the formatting. 
`ps -xco %cpu,command | grep AvidMediaComposer `

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question:

I tried a few things and canned the idea of checking for the CPU load for a variety of reasons. 
I'm using the following code

```
prev_size=-1 # initialize variable
new_size=`/usr/bin/du -sk "$file_i" | awk '{print $1}'` # get current file size

while [ $prev_size != $new_size ] # repeat until these values are the same
do
/bin/sleep 5 # check every 5 seconds
tmp_size=$new_size # move to intermediate value
new_size=`/usr/bin/du -sk "$file_i" | awk '{print $1}'` # get new file size
prev_size=$tmp_size
done
```

which I found [here](http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/153036-check-if-file-finished-copy.html), relying on the directory size.
While it's not perfect, it's good enough for my purposes.
Hope I have some more time to work on this, will post the code to my scripts when done.

Answer (score 0):

```
fswatch -xn /Users/...... | while read file; do
 while [ `lsof -t $file` > 0 ]; do sleep .1; done
  ffmpeg........
done
```